# This Cookie works on Localhost But it doesn't work on main site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This Cookie works on Localhost But it doesn't work on the main site. 
    Help!! me guys.
   I tried everything and did everything but still, it didn't work.I searched everywhere about this problem and found nothing about it.Therefore,I posted here so i could solve this issue.Also,Is there any other easy methods or hacks for this specific problem??

```
<?php 
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pramit", "root", "");
    $message = '';
    if(isset($_POST["add_to_favourite"]))
    {
        if(isset($_COOKIE["event_c"]))
        {
            $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['event_c']);
            $event_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
        }
        else
        {
            $event_data = array();
        }
        $event_id_list = array_column($event_data, 'event_id');
        if(in_array($_POST["hidden_id"], $event_id_list))
        {
            foreach($event_data as $keys => $values)
            {
                if($event_data[$keys]["event_id"] == $_POST["hidden_id"])
                {
                    $event_data[$keys]["event_quantity"] = $event_data[$keys]["event_quantity"] + $_POST["quantity"];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $event_array = array(
                'event_id'          =>  $_POST["hidden_id"],
                'event_name'            =>  $_POST["hidden_name"],
                'event_date'        =>  $_POST["hidden_date"],
                'event_quantity'        =>  $_POST["quantity"]
            );
            $event_data[] = $event_array;
        }
        $event_data = json_encode($event_data);
        setcookie('event_c', $event_data, time() + (86400 * 30));
        header("location:index.php?success=1");
    }
    if(isset($_GET["action"]))
    {
        if($_GET["action"] == "delete")
        {
            $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['event_c']);
            $event_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
            foreach($event_data as $keys => $values)
            {
                if($event_data[$keys]['event_id'] == $_GET["id"])
                {
                    unset($event_data[$keys]);
                    $event_data = json_encode($event_data);
                    setcookie("event_c", $event_data, time() + (86400 * 30));
                    header("location:index.php?remove=1");
                }
            }
        }
        if($_GET["action"] == "clear")
        {
            setcookie("event_c", "", time() - 3600);
            header("location:index.php?clearall=1");
        }
    }
    if(isset($_GET["success"]))
    {
        $message = '
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            Event Added to favourite 
        </div>
        ';
    }
    if(isset($_GET["remove"]))
    {
        $message = '
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            Event Removed
        </div>
        ';
    }
    if(isset($_GET["clearall"]))
    {
        $message = '
        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close">&times;</a>
            Your Favourite is cleared....You are free to go..........
        </div>
        ';
    }
    ?>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Event Favourite</title>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <br />
            <div class="container">
                <br />
                <h3 align="center">Event Favourite</h3><br />
                <br /><br />
                <?php
                $query = "SELECT * FROM event_favourite ORDER BY id ASC";
                $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
                $statement->execute();
                $result = $statement->fetchAll();
                foreach($result as $row)
                {
                ?>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <form method="post">
                        <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">
                            <img src="images/<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />

                            <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>
                            <h4 class="text-danger"> <?php echo $row["date"]; ?></h4>

                        <!--    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1" class="form-control" />-->
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_date" value="<?php echo $row["date"]; ?>" />
                            <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" value="<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>" />
                            <input type="submit" name="add_to_favourite" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to favourite" />
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>
                <br />
                <h3>Event Details</h3>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                <?php echo $message; ?>
                <div align="right">
                    <a href="index.php?action=clear"><b>Clear Event</b></a>
                </div>
                <table class="table table-bordered">
                    <tr>
                        <th width="40%">Event Name</th>
                        <th width="1%">---</th>
                        <th width="20%">date</th>
                        <th width="1%">----</th>
                        <th width="5%">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                if(isset($_COOKIE["event_c"]))
                {
                    $total = 0;
                    $cookie_data = stripslashes($_COOKIE['event_c']);
                    $event_data = json_decode($cookie_data, true);
                    foreach($event_data as $keys => $values)
                    {
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?php echo $values["event_name"]; ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo $values["event_quantity"]; ?></td>
                        <td> <?php echo $values["event_date"]; ?></td>
                        <td> <?php// echo number_format($values["event_quantity"] * $values["event_date"], 2);?></td>
                        <td><a href="index.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["event_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php   
                        //$total = $total + ($values["event_quantity"] * $values["event_date"]);
                    }
                ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="3" align="right"></td>
                        <td align="right"> <?php// echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php
                }
                else
                {
                    echo '
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="5" align="center">No Event Added to favourite</td>
                    </tr>
                    ';
                }
                ?>
```

Comment: You miss a `"` when creating a PDO connection object, is it a copy-paste error?

Comment: oops..Yes it is...